# Visual Studio 2012's Intellisense no longer accepting suggestion on spacebar press

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I've been using Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010 on multiple PC's, installed there by other person or by me. Always intellisense suggestion on it worked like this:

I start typing, window pops with suggestions, with current suggestion highlighted, and I can press spacebar to accept the suggestion.

However, since i installed Visual Studio 2012 on my current PC (it is a relatively fresh Win7 64x install, it had VS2010 installed before) it works differently.

Now, it no longer highlights the suggestion. I have to use CTRL+ENTER to accept suggestion or DOWN to make it selected so that spacebar will accept it. This is really uncomfortable to use.

I tried resetting my settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset Settings) but it didnt help. It tried looking for help but noone knows or has this problem it seems.

What am I doing wrong? How to revert to old behavior?

Comment: Did you already try toggling intellisense completion mode using `CTRL + ALT + SPACE`?

Comment: CTRL+ALT+SPACE does nothing. CTRL+SPACE shows the completion mode which works the same (the suggestion is not highlighted but boxed, i have to press down to select it or ctrl+enter to use it)

Comment: `CTRL+ALT+SPACE` does toggle the IntelliSense Completion Mode: Check `Edit | IntelliSense | Toggle Completion Mode (like Jarek suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have **Toggle Completion Mode** selected in Edit | IntelliSense menu?
If so then click on it to unselect it.

Comment: Oh... well.. Seems like it. Too bad its on a pretty common hotkey, I must have done this accidentally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I had the same problem. I know this worked for me when I was working with Java Script at least. Go to **Tools>Options>Text Editor>JavaScript>IntelliSense** Then make sure that the "Only use Tab or Enter to commit" is UN checked. Hope this helps, or at least gets you on the right track.

Comment: The `Toggle Completion Mode` option is grayed out for me, but this works. Thanks!