# Intellisense not showing variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, code-completion

I have found cases where IntelliSense will not suggest variables where it should:

```cpp
struct A
{
    const int m_Int;

    A(A& other) : m_Int(other.m_Int) // doesn't suggest m_Int
    {
        int l_Int(other.m_Int); // doesn't suggest m_Int
        l_Int = other.m_Int; // doesn't suggest other, but m_Int works here
    }

};
```

The first two times where I wrote `other.`, it should have popped up a suggestions window with the member `m_Int` but it didn't.

After typing `l_Int = o` it also didn't let me autocomplete to `l_Int = other`.

In all of these cases, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't help either.

Is there a setting that is set wrong on my end?
I tried a few solutions from the internet to reset my settings, but nothing changed.

It happens in a new empty Visual C++ project with just the shown content.(Plus obvious boilerplate)
Does somebody not have these problems and gets the correct IntelliSense recommendations?

The project compiles without errors.
Version: MSVS Enterprise 2017 15.9.13
No Extensions activated

Comment: I think I've had this issue when developing with C# and VB.NET and the only thing that seemed to help for a while was restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: @theblackips I always have this problem, be it after booting my PC, reopening VS while leaving the PC running, new projects, old projects.

Comment: If you have any VS extensions enabled, could you add them to your question including their version?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744780/visual-studio-2012s-intellisense-no-longer-accepting-suggestion-on-spacebar-pre?rq=1

Comment: This question currently being discussed on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386739/8239061

Comment: @theblackips I didn't see any feedback from the program when using the shortcut from your linked Q&A, but tried anyway. No suggested variables...

Comment: @theblackips did you try my example and did you get member variable suggestions at the places i miss them?

Comment: @DanielBauer Yes, I can confirm this issue as you described it in VS Community 2017 v15.2. Maybe time for a bug report?

Comment: @DanielBauer In my case when I press Ctrl+Space in one of the first two places VS displays the message `IntelliSense: "No members available"` in the bottom left corner

Comment: I reported the problem to microsoft https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/640890/intellisense-no-member-found-where-it-should.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the setting is **intellisenseEngine: Default**, **intellisenseEngineFallback: enable**. After you make these changes in your vs code, it works perfectly. Otherwise, you can also change the *intellisenseEngineFallback: disable*.